# Java - How to improve Performance of a function using Redis Cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, caching, redis

I have the below function. I need to improve its performance.
I thought of using Redis Cache to achieve the same.

```
public List<Price> loadPrices( List<Product> products )
    {
        List<Price> priceList = new ArrayList<Price>();
        for ( Product product : products )
        {
            Price price= loadPrices( product );
            priceList.add( offering );
        }
        return priceList;
    }


public Price loadPrices( Product product )
    {
        Price price = new Price();
        //some more code and for loop
        return price;
    }
```

The code is written in the Spring Boot project.
I'm new to Redis Cache. I'm unable to understand How can I make use of caching annotation available in Spring Boot to improve performance.

Assuming product list is very huge.

I'm aware of @EnableCaching, and @Cacheable  annotation. However I'm not sure how to use them here.

Can someone help me What is an efficient way to cache the data?

Comment: assuming the load prices call is slow and/or the number of products is huge -- you can cache the priceList -- but without knowing why its slow it is difficult to determine whether caching will even help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Number of products is huge. However I’m not sure how can I cache it using spring boot. Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: how many instances of your services will be up and running? how often do you need to spin up new instances of the service?

Comment: You don't cache via spring boot - use a caching client like caffeine or lettuce for redis and put the product list in there

Comment: Thanks, Asad for your reply. I need to come up with statistics regarding performance improvement. What are the parameters you think I should measure? One I can think of is the time to load the product list. How can I achieve the same? Is there any library available in spring boot?